# Validation layer based on rules

Tags: c#, validation, generics, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement [this pattern](https://mentormate.com/bg/blog/modern-validation-patterns-in-c-sharp/).

Starting from the caller I would like to do something like that:

```
var validatore = new Validator();

validatore.AddRule<TestRule>("OK");
validatore.AddRule<int>(45);

validatore.Validate();
```

The implementation of the rules:

```
public interface IValidationRule<T>
{
    string Error { get; set; }
    bool Validate(T arg);
}

public class TestRule : IValidationRule<string>
{
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public bool Validate(string arg)
    {
        return arg == "test";
    }
}
```

The problem is the concrete implementation of the validator.
I assumed something like that:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    void AddRule<TRule>(dynamic arg);
    ValidationResult Validate();
}

public class Validator : IValidator
{
    public void AddRule<T>(dynamic arg)
    {
        ???
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate()
    {
        forEach ...
    }
}
```

Where should i put every generic rule in a single collection object (AddRule)?
Is my like-implementation on the right way?

Comment: [What design pattern to use for validating data and creating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540583/what-design-pattern-to-use-for-validating-data-and-creating-an-object) might be helpful.

Comment: Depending on your use case you could either use a simple Collection or something more specific (e.g. a Concurrentlist<T> if you have multiple threads adding Validators) but you probably need some kind of Collection to hold all Rules you ind your Validator

Comment: @Brezelmann, is this the point. I think i need some kind of collection where iterate objects. The key point is that every object has different type and i don't know how to aggregate them in a single structure.

Comment: Isn't every Validationrule inheriting from the IValidationRule Interface? If they are you could use that to use a Collection<IValidationRule> that can hold every possible implementation of IvalidationRule. You have to just new up the Rule that you specified as Type and put that then in the Collection

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is a bit too abstract to begin with. In the sense that you end up with more useful generalizations if you start with what precisely you  want to do and then make abstractions on top of that. Like, in this case, it is not obvious, what is being validated? User input in some UI? Or data from some xml? In the first case, you would not only need an error message, but likely also some action that updates the UI, according to your error. And then the validation abstraction would likely take a rather different shape. And where from will the actual code come, that does the validating? Having to implement special classes for each validation rule will make an awsome abstraction but unnecessarily complicated code when you actually want to use it.

Also, I would use dynamic type only when there absolutely is no other way.

So, assuming you are still interested, the code below would work with validating reference types. Then again, if you need a validation system, the value types that you would need to validate are typically properties of some class, but still good to keep in mind that it's not universal.

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; } = false;
    public string ErrorText { get; set; } = "No error";
    public void SetError(string errorMsg)
    {
        this.HasError = true;
        ErrorText = errorMsg;
    }
}

public interface IValidationRule
{
    ValidationResult Validate();
}

public class ValidationRule<T> : IValidationRule
{
    private Func<T, ValidationResult> validatorFunc;
    private T validationSubject;
    public ValidationRule(T validationSubject, Func<T, ValidationResult> validatorFunc)
    {
        this.validationSubject = validationSubject;
        this.validatorFunc = validatorFunc;
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate() => validatorFunc?.Invoke(validationSubject);
}

public interface IValidator
{
    void AddRule<T>(T validationSubject, Func<T, ValidationResult> validationFunc);
    ValidationResult Validate();
}

public class Validator : IValidator
{
    private readonly List<IValidationRule> rules = new List<IValidationRule>();

    public void AddRule<T>(T validationSubject, Func<T,ValidationResult> validationFunc)
    {
        rules.Add(new ValidationRule<T>(validationSubject, validationFunc));
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate()
    {
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            var result = rule.Validate();
            if (result.HasError) return result;
        }

        return new ValidationResult();
    }
}
```

To add a validation rule, you pass in two parameters: an object to be validated some time later, and a Func that contains the logic and returns ValidationResult. Like this:

```
public class ValidatableObject
{
    public int intValue;
}

private void Test()
{
    var target = new ValidatableObject();
    target.intValue = 1;

    var validator = new Validator();
    validator.AddRule(target, (x) =>
    {
        var validationResult = new ValidationResult();
        if (x.intValue > 10) validationResult.SetError("Exceeds max value (10)");
        return validationResult;
    });

    log(validator.Validate().ErrorText);
    target.intValie = 100;
    log(validator.Validate().ErrorText);
}
```